# 1) Reordering one csv file based on another file header and 2) Merging one column of one csv file to another and remove duplicate

Tags: bash, awk, sed, miller

I have two csv file.
Both files might have same or different data. File2 has only few columns from file 1. Some column in file 2 may have different header. eg File 2 has Name in place of First Name

```
Username, Identifier,One-time password,Recovery code,First name,Last name,Department,Location
booker12,9012,12se74,rb9012,Rachel,Booker,Sales,Manchester
grey07,2070,04ap67,lg2070,Laura,Grey,Depot,London
johnson81,4081,30no86,cj4081,Craig,Johnson,Depot,London
jenkins46,9346,14ju73,mj9346,Mary,Jenkins,Engineering,Manchester
smith79,5079,09ja61,js5079,Jamie,Smith,Engineering,Manchester
```

File 2

```
Department,First name,Last name,One-time password
Sales,Rachel,Booker,12se74
Depot,Laura,Grey,04ap67
Depot,Craig,Johnson,30no86
Engineering,Mary,Jenkins,14ju73
Engineering,Jamie,Smith,09ja61
```

**Problem 1:**
I wanted to reorder columns in  csv file 2 to match order in  csv file 1 based on headers.

**Desired output header sorted based on file 1**

```
One-time password,Name,Last name,Department
12se74,Dash,Bok,Sales
04ap67,Claire,Trans,Accounts
30no86,Shane,Walter,Depot
14ju73,Leon,Jenkins,Engineering
09ja61,Oliver,Den,Engineering
```

**Problem 2:**
Merge File2 columns to File 1 based on header removing duplicates
Eg if First Name , Last Name, Department columns are same then those are duplicates remove those dupes.
Other columns may or may not be same.
**Hence wanting to achive condition based deduplication of record**

**Problem 3:**
Convert file 2 as file 1 template add missing columns in order. Finally compare and delete duplicate columns based on certain headers. **eg. If First Name, Last Name and password are same then they are duplicates other columns may be same or different.**

**Problem 4:**
Copy specific column from file 2 to file 1 preserving order
*Eg. File 2 has Name column Replace that column with First Name column of file 1*

Tried:

```
awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, 'FNR==NR{hash[FNR]=$5; next}{$2 = hash[FNR]}1' file file2
```

Above answer is from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674038/replace-a-column-value-in-csv-file-from-another-file

Above seem to work. But it requires to specify column numbet as $5 and $2. Can anyone help modify above command to specify header instead of column number

Tried

```
awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if (i=="name") var=$i }; FNR==NR{hash[FNR]=$5; next}{$var = hash[FNR] }' file file2
```

Not working

Comment: Don't ask multiple questions ("Problems") in 1 question, just ask 1 question then see if you can adapt the answer you get for that before asking any followup questions **if necessary**. Also make sure to include exactly the expected output for your posted sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all quite easily with [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is available [here](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases/) as a static binary. Put the `mlr` executable somewhere in your PATH and you're done with the installation.

---

**For starters**, I'll assume that we're working with two CSV files **with no inconsistency in the column names**:

```sh
cat file1.csv
```

```
Username, Identifier,One-time password,Recovery code,First name,Last name,Department,Location
booker12,9012,12se74,rb9012,Rachel,Booker,Sales,Manchester
```

```sh
cat file2.csv
```

```
Department,First name,Last name,One-time password
Engineering,Oliver,Den,09ja61
Sales,Rachel,Booker,12se74
```

---

###### rename a specified field:

```sh
mlr --csv rename 'First name,Name' file2.csv
```

```
Department,Name,Last name,One-time password
Engineering,Oliver,Den,09ja61
Sales,Rachel,Booker,12se74
```

---

###### re-order the columns of `file2.csv` based on the header of `file1.csv`:

```sh
mlr --csv reorder -f "$(head -n 1 file1.csv)" file2.csv
```

```
One-time password,First name,Last name,Department
09ja61,Oliver,Den,Engineering
12se74,Rachel,Booker,Sales
```

---

###### add missing columns in `file2.csv` based on the header of `file1.csv`:

```sh
mlr --csv template -t file1.csv file2.csv
```

```
Username, Identifier,One-time password,Recovery code,First name,Last name,Department,Location
,,09ja61,,Oliver,Den,Engineering,
,,12se74,,Rachel,Booker,Sales,
```

---

###### remove duplicates based on `One-time password,First name,Last name` unicity:

```sh
mlr --csv head -n 1 -g 'One-time password,First name,Last name' fileX.csv
```

---

###### concatenate `file1.csv` and `file2.csv`:

```sh
mlr --csv unsparsify file1.csv file2.csv
```

```
Username, Identifier,One-time password,Recovery code,First name,Last name,Department,Location
booker12,9012,12se74,rb9012,Rachel,Booker,Sales,Manchester
,,09ja61,,Oliver,Den,Engineering,
,,12se74,,Rachel,Booker,Sales,
```

---

###### concatenate `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` and remove the duplicates based on `One-time password,First name,Last name` unicity:

The command is composed of a chain of operations.

```sh
mlr --csv unsparsify then head -n 1 -g 'One-time password,First name,Last name' file1.csv file2.csv
```

```
Username, Identifier,One-time password,Recovery code,First name,Last name,Department,Location
booker12,9012,12se74,rb9012,Rachel,Booker,Sales,Manchester
,,09ja61,,Oliver,Den,Engineering,
```

---

**Lastly**, let's suppose that the column `First name` is called `Name` in `file2.csv` and that you want to concatenate `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` and remove the duplicates based on `One-time password,First name,Last name` unicity.

You can do it by prepending a `rename` operation to the previous command:

```sh
mlr --csv rename 'Name,First name' then unsparsify then head -n 1 -g 'One-time password,First name,Last name' file1.csv file2.csv
```

Comment: Thanks. For Problem 4 eg.  copy 5nd column of file1 to 2nd column of file 1. First Name column of file 1 to Name column of second file and vice versa

Comment: Wouldn't that be just changing the column name in the header?

Comment: Data may be different sometime

Comment: Sir. Using unsparsify and implode i wanted to merge two csv files and then remove all duplicates. But duplicates doesny measn all columns have same value and can be removed with sort -u. Instead if records have certain columns withsame values then they are considerd duplicates and can be trimmed to single entry